# MongoDB exception: WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a MongoDB collection.

I want to change the indexing, to have a dual index, rather than a single.

So I ran:

```
db.allnews.ensureIndex( { "url": 1, "source": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

But then I get the error:

```
exception: WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index
```

And the limit is 1024 bytes

So what is the solution...?

(1) Ignore it somehow.. somehow skip these records that are too long, without stopping the entire process..?

```
--setParameter failIndexKeyTooLong=false
```

?? Could this do the trick..?

(2) Find the records that are too long, through some sort of query, and shorten them..?

(3) Something else..?

Answer (score 6):

OK, I solved my issue.

Run this:

```
db.getSiblingDB('admin').runCommand( { setParameter: 1, failIndexKeyTooLong: false } )
```

Then you can create your dual index without  it throwing an error

```
db.getCollection("allnews").ensureIndex( { "url": 1, "source": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```